# Combine two different rules in HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was finally able to successfully create a Rule in my HTACCESS file, to hide a sub-folder.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Project/$2.php [NC,L]
```

The first rule removes all file-extensions :  php

The second rule will hide the folder "Project" from the URL

Both these rules are working perfectly.

However, when I tried to add a third rule, to hide another folder, it failed.

This second folder (Rolan) is in the same location as the "Project" folder, so I assumed that it should work simply by copy-pasting the second rule :

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Project/$2.php 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Rolan/$2.php [NC,L]
```

(Please note :  I removed the **[NC,L]** from the end of the second rule, and placed it at the end of the third rule.)

Both the first and second rules are still working.  But, for the third rule, I am getting a "**FILE NOT FOUND : 404**"  error

**UPDATE**

I have modified my HTACCESS file, as follows :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Project/$2.php
 RewriteRule ^gagoo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Rolan/$2.php [NC,L]
```

I added the prefix "**gagoo**" to the third rule.

Then, in my php code, I use the URL :  **/gagoo/Rolan/file_name**

But, I am still getting a 404 error.

I tried removing the "Rolan" from the URL :   **/gagoo/file_name**

And, still no luck.

Actually, the way the rule works, the "Rolan" is not supposed to be included in the URL  (after all, the purpose of the Rule is to hide the "Rolan" folder from display in the browser........the same way the second rule hides the "PHP" folder)

Comment: You have same pattern `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` for both rules that's why only first one will work. You will need to have some prefix for 2nd one like `r/foo/bar` or something else.

Comment: The problem is that `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` is very generic and will match whatever URIs you intend to place into `Rolan` and send them instead to `Project` (where they probably generate 404's). What specifically differentiates URIs in `Project` from those in `Rolan`?

Comment: @anubhava :  so, I need to add something to the "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$", to make it different?   If I made the second rule like this :   ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$rrrrrrr.................for example.  Will this work?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:  nothing differentiates them.  Both folders contain simple PHP files.

Comment: No both pretty URLs will also be different. You will be using `http://domain.com/r/folder/file` like URLs

Comment: @anubhava: ok, what kind of "prefix" could I add, to make it work?

Comment: Anything you like e.g. look at URL of above question that has  `/questions/` prefix.

Comment: @anubhava: please, could you be a bit more specific??  " ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$"...............and then what?  You said that adding "rrrr" won't work, but then you say I can add anything I like.

Comment: I've already answered all of your questions actually in comments above. Use: `RewriteRule ^prefix/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/Project/$2.php [NC,L]` and the have URL as: `http://domain.com/prefix/folder/file`

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, it's not working.  I updated my post, to show the new HTACCESS file I am using.  The first 2 rules are still working just fine.  But, the third rule  (for "Rolan"), is still giving me a 404 error